# How do I find a specific path on the firebase realtime database then change the value at that path using a Text Input?

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Pop quiz, hotshot:

You're building a react native app.  You set some values to firebase as an object at the root of your app, like this:

```
firebase
      .database()
      .ref("/companies/")
      .set({
        awesomeCompany: {
          name: "Awesome Company",
          owner: "Joe Awesome",
          gmail: "joeawesome@gmail.com",
          fleetSize: 2
        },
        badCompany: {
          name: "Bad Company",
          owner: "Joe Bad",
          gmail: "joebad@gmail.com",
          fleetSize: 3
        }
```

You want to give the current user a text input field through which they may change the fleetSize of a company if they are the owner of that company.

You have your firebase auth working properly, so you know that `firebase.auth().currentUser.email` will work to check against to determine if they are an owner.

Your database values have been set - they look like this:

```
{
  "companies": {
    "awesomeCompany": {
      "fleetSize": 2,
      "gmail": "joeawesome@gmail.com",
      "name": "Awesome Company",
      "owner": "Joe Awesome"
    },
    "badCompany": {
      "fleetSize": 3,
      "gmail": "joebad@gmail.com",
      "name": "Bad Company",
      "owner": "Joe Bad"
    }
  }
}
```

How would you render the initial information to the screen, and how would you set up the text input logic so that the user input changes data at the database?

To understand the brain I have, and how I'm failing, I'm including my own code below as a starting point.  If there's a way to show me how I could take my basic strategy and make it work - even if it isn't elegant - I'd appreciate that.  But overall I'm just really struggling with how to get data path references using Data Snapshot and keep them available to use elsewhere.

Thanks for your help, anyone!

```
// my crummy half baked code below
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, TextInput, Button } from "react-native";
import { styles } from "../styles";
import * as firebase from "firebase";

export default class OwnerProfileScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      gmail: null,
      name: null,
      fleetSize: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData = () => {
    const rootRef = firebase.database().ref(); // firebase reference
    const authEmail = firebase.auth().currentUser.email; // current user

    return rootRef.once("value").then(
      function(snapshot) {
        const idArray = Object.keys(snapshot.child("companies/").val()); // array of Ids

        const companyData = idArray.map(id =>
          snapshot.child("companies/" + id).val()
        ); //  values of contained in objects at each key

        const ownersCompany = companyData.filter(
          obj => obj.gmail === authEmail
        ); // an array containing one object if the gmail address in the object is the same as the currentUser logged in


           // what is the path of fleetSize?  
           // how do I define it to keep it available to use later 
           // with a Text Input event?

        this.setState({
          name: ownersCompany[0].name,
          gmail: ownersCompany[0].gmail,
          fleetSize: ownersCompany[0].fleetSize
        });
      }.bind(this)
    );
  };

  changeFleetSize = userInput => {
    //in order to set the user input to the database, I need the path
    //of the fleetSize of the current user (who has been verified as an 
    // owner by comparing firebase auth to gmail addresses of company)
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>minPrice = {this.state.name}</Text>
        <Text>gmail = {this.state.gmail}</Text>
        <Text>fleetSize = {this.state.fleetSize}</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={{ height: 40, borderColor: "gray", borderWidth: 1 }}
          //onChangeText currently does nothing since I don't know how
          // to get the particular path of particular fleetSize 
          onChangeText={userInput => this.changeFleetSize(userInput)} 
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks; changed JSON to text.

Comment: What is the problem when you run this code again the JSON? Which line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: I added a few comments in the code to clarify what I'm trying to solve; no problem with the JSON as far as I know.  I have rendered a few values by finding them, but I do not understand how to save their path to refer to later.  To clarify, if I could define something like `const ownersFleetSizePath = firebase.database().ref("companies/" + ownerCompanyId)` then, upon a Text Input, I would try to set a value at that path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is quite messy so it's hard to say what you're trying to accomplish. But let me make a guess here:

1. You want to load a single company from your database.
2. You know the email address of the owner of the company.

If that is correct, you can use a query to accomplish the goal. Something like:

```
var query = rootRef.child("companies").orderByChild("gmail").equalTo(authEmail);
var self = this;
query.once("value").then(function(result) {
  result.forEach(function(snapshot) { // loop over result snapshots, since there may be multiple
    const companyData = snapshot.val();

    self.setState({
      name: companyData.name,
      gmail: companyData.gmail,
      fleetSize: companyData.fleetSize
    });
  })
);
```

The changes here:

1. Use a query to only select the companies with the correct gmail address.
2. Loop over the results, since (on an API level at least) there could be multiple companies with that value for their `gmail` property.
3. Get rid of the whole iterating over `Object.keys` and filtering, since that made it hard to read. This result is also more idiomatic for Firebase Realtime Database code.
4. Use `self` to track the `this` instance, just because I didn't feel like counting `bind` calls.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.  I agree that is a *much* better way to get to and render the information, and that my code is a mess :). I'll try to narrow the focus more.  In the TextInput component, I take the userInput and want to write it directly to the database.  To do so, I imagine I'll need a function like this `writeNewFleetSizeToDatabase = userInput => {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref("companies/" + companyId)
      .set({
        fleetSize: userInput
      }); 
  };
`       How do I get the right companyId?

Comment: I'm confused. So the question wasn't about reading, but only about writing data? :-/

Comment: Sorry about creating confusion.  The goal was: Read, Write, Read again.  Read from database, render to screen; when user inputs text to change fleetSize, write to database, then render to screen again immediately.  To accomplish the Write portion, I copied much of your (@Frank) code, and from where you left off `const companyData = snapshot.val();` was able to figure out how to get the companyId 
`const companyDataId = snapshot.ref.key;`

Comment: Frank - just want to say thanks for your effort to help a noob!  Very much appreciated.